# Archimedes PI Approximation in Python

Tags: python

[image]

Here is my code thus far,

```
from math import *

def main():
    sides = eval(input("Enter the number of sides:"))

    value = 360/(2 * sides)
    sinvalue = sin(value)
    PI = sinvalue * sides

    print("Approximate value of pi =", PI)
```

However, I am not getting the proper value that is in the sample code.

Comment: What value are you getting? Have you considered floating-point errors?

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you're using degrees instead of radians.  Change 360 to 2*pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math.sin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin) expects angles to be specified in radians.

```
>>> print(math.sin.__doc__)
sin(x)

Return the sine of x (measured in radians).
```

You are specifying it in degrees.  Specify the angle in radians instead:

```
value = math.pi / sides
```

Or, if you don't want to use `math.pi` so explicitly, use the helper function to convert units:

```
value = math.radians(360/(2*sides))
```

Comment: Correct, but the approximation of Pi becomes somewhat pointless if you have to use `math.pi` in the process...

Comment: @tobias_k  I guess the point is to see the convergence as the number of `sides` increases.  That's actually the same as the `sin(x) = x` approximation for small `x`.

Comment: Added an alternative that sweeps the usage of `math.pi` under the rug... ;)